# IOS Swift OTP Code Autofill doesn't work on all devices

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement OTP SMS codes to verify user identity.

I'm doing this by setting UITextField as follows:

textBox.keyboardType = .numberPad

textBox.textContentType = .oneTimeCode

Whilst this works it doesn't work on every device: On some devices the SMS arrives and I get the option at the top of the keyboard to use it. On other devices although I see the dialog for the SMS arriving there is no option to use it on the keyboard.

I can't find a setting in the device to activate this feature. I steer a way to ensure this feature is available on every device?